# How to access hibernate session via AnnotationSessionFactoryBean?

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I want to integrate hibernate with spring. spring 3 documentation says that you can access session via org.hiberate.SessionFactory's getCurrentSession() and this should be prefered over hibernateDaoSupport approach.

But I want to know how can we get hold of org.hiberate.SessionFactory's instance in the first place if we are using AnnotationSessionFactoryBean? 
I have done the following bean declaration in applicationContext.xml:

```
       <bean id="annotationSessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
              <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mydomain"/>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                  <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                  </props>
            </property>     
    </bean>
```

DAO which is using the session:

```
    <bean id="hibernateUserProfileDAO" class="com.springheatmvn.Dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserProfileDAO">
        <property name="annotationSessionFactoryBean" ref="annotationSessionFactoryBean"/>
    </bean>
```

In my hibernateUserProfileDAO I would like to get the current session like this

```
    public class HibernateUserProfileDAO implements UserProfileDAO {
      private AnnotationSessionFactoryBean annotationSessionFactoryBean;

      public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
    Session session = annotationSessionFactoryBean.getCurrentSession();
      ....
      }
```

But I see that there is no public getCurrentSession() method in AnnotationFactoryBean. I found only protected getAnnotationSession() method but it is also on Abstract session factory class.

Can any one please tell me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` is a factory that produces `SessionFactory` automatically (Spring handles in internally), so that you need to use it as follows:

```
<bean id="sf" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">        
    ...
</bean>    

<bean id="hibernateUserProfileDAO" class="com.springheatmvn.Dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserProfileDAO">
     <property name="sf" ref="sf"/>
</bean>
```

.

```
public class HibernateUserProfileDAO implements UserProfileDAO {
    private SessionFactory sf;    
    ...
}
```

Then you obtain a `Session` by calling `sf.getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: Sorry, but now that confuses me further, how is it converting instance of spring's annotationSessionFactoryBean into an instance of org.hiberate.SessionFactory's instance?

Comment: Spring does it internally, see [3.8.3 Customizing instantiation logic with the FactoryBean Interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean).

Comment: The reason I'm asking all this is because when I'm trying to do sf.getCurrentSession() I'm getting the following exception:   org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Comment: `SessionFactory` created by `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` is intended for use with Spring-managed transactions, [see docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate).