# error in spring xml file .need guidance with spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and am going through example programs in spring....My program is as below

User.java

```
package project2;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String password;
private String gender;
private String country;


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="USER_ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="USER_NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="USER_PASSWORD")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name="USER_GENDER")
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Column(name="USER_COUNTRY")
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}


}
```

UserDAO.java

```
package project2;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserDAO {

    public void saveUser(User user) ;
    public List<User> listUser() ;
    public void deleteUser(User user) ;
}
```

UserController2.java

```
package project2;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;


@Controller
public class UserController2 extends MultiActionController {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }
    @RequestMapping(params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, User user) throws Exception {
        userDAO.saveUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }
    @RequestMapping(params = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView delete(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, User user) throws Exception {
        userDAO.deleteUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }

    public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.addAttribute("userList", userDAO.listUser());
        modelMap.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return new ModelAndView("userForm", modelMap);
    }
}
```

UserDAOImpl.java

```
package project2;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return hibernateTemplate.find("from User");
   }

     @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.delete(user);
    }
 }
```

and the UserController2-servlet.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>


<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indi"/>
    <property name="username" value="admin"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>Spring.project2.User</value>

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myUserDAO" class="project2.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean name="/user/*.htm" class="project2.UserController2" >
    <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
</bean>


<bean name="indexController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="userForm" />

</beans>
```

and the userForm.jsp file is as follows

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center> WELCOME TO CUSTOMER ACCESS SITE.PLEASE ENTER THE FOLLOWING  
                 INFORMATION</center>
<form:form method="POST" action="add.htm" commandName="user">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td><form:label path="password">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><form:label path="gender">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="gender" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><form:label path="gender">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="gender" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><form:label path="country">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="country" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>  
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the web.xml file is as follows...

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserController2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserController2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

now when i run this program i get nested exceptions in my UserController2-servlet.xml file as follows

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class  
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0'  
defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/UserController2-servlet.xml]:  
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is  
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 '/user/*.htm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/UserController2-
servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myUserDAO' while setting bean property
 'userDAO'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'myUserDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/UserController2-
servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean 
property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/UserController2-
servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of 
type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 
'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot 
find class [Spring.project2.User]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Spring.project2.User
   at  
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
at 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:290)
```

I have saved these file under folder project2 in src and the project name is Spring. I have included all the jar files in lib and all jars are of same version. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UserController2-servlet.xml` see this declaration, change `Spring.project2.User` to `project2.User`

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"     
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
       <list>
          <value>Spring.project2.User</value>
          ....
```

Comment: It should be `<value>project2.User</value>` and not `<value>Spring.project2.User</value>` - And this did not work?

Comment: yep i shows the same error as"nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot 
find class [project2.User]"

Comment: Try replacing `<property name="annotatedClasses"> .. ` with `<property name="packagesToScan" value="project2"/>`. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389239/how-to-access-hibernate-session-via-annotationsessionfactorybean]

Comment: Interesting, is it a war deployment? If so, can you see your classes in `/webapps/Spring/WEB-INF/classes` folder?

Comment: I changed it to packageToScan like you specified...and the error was gone

Answer (score 1):

Use scanner to find entities:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>project2.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>

            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Hope to help you:)

Comment: I guess you are asking the error stack trace...i posted it along with the question above

Answer (score 0):

see here

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot 
find class [Spring.project2.User]
```

Change `Spring.project2.User` to `project2.User`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Spring string, like following it'll work fine

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>project2.User</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

Good luck:)

Comment: then where should i specify tht i am using an annotated class

Comment: another way, you can use scanner in hibernate to specify the directory of entities. see my anothe answer:)